# Memory usage for EventHandler<UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs>

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, async-await, owin, azure-service-fabric

During memory profiling of my application (.NET owin service hosted on top of service fabric) I noticed `EventHandler<UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs>` has 24 instances each has size 1880B, but inclusive size - which I take is the object + all references around 1.2GB.

I take it this is somehow related to exceptions in unawaited tasks.
Can this be a culprint or is it a red herring - and also why it is in memory dump in first place ?

Comment: I suppose it is not impossible.  It wraps an AggregateException which has a ReadOnlyCollection of Exceptions.  A jiggabyte worth of exceptions is, well, something that ought to be debuggable.

Comment: @HansPassant yes [1.21 _jiggabytes_](https://tenor.com/view/1point21gigawatts-back-to-the-future-doc-gif-9470027) should certainly be debuggable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is part of service fabric infrastructure. Statefull service replica hooks itself to `Task.UnobservedTaskException` for some internal monitoring. It also gracefully deregister itself. The memory allocated is this big because of state dictionaries associated with replica.

Comment: We're seeing this too. Did you end up finding a way of bringing this down to something more reasonable? Or does your answer mean that's actually what you're expecting for the size of your service's state?

Comment: @NickDarvey - my answer basically means you can disregard the Task.UnobservedTaskException for purposes of memory leak analysis, it has reference to statefull replica dictionaries and that's why it is so big. My real issue was with reliable dictionary; you can check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776645/removing-items-from-reliable-dictionary-doesnt-actually-remove-them-from-memory